# Reading raw bytes from directory in android

Tags: android, linux, byte, dd

How I could read out raw bytes from the sd card (/mnt/sdcard) in android? Sure, I need root access but is it possible in general or not. In linux i can use the dd command `dd if=<source> of=<target> bs=<byte size>` and write raw bytes in a temporary file. What is the solution in Android?

Comment: you want to read from file or to write to file?

Comment: No, the sd card by itself should be the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android is still Linux underneath and has the `dd` binary as part of the system. You can use it just like on any other Linux install. You can find it in `/system/bin/dd`.